# Error while changing default controller in codeiniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my controller.php and route.php files.

Index_controller.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Index_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function index()
    {
        echo "i am here"; die();
        if($this->session->userdata('user_role')=="Employer")
        {
            redirect('/pages/dashboard/get_empr_info', 'refresh'); //refresh..?
        }
        if($this->session->userdata('user_role')=="Employee")
        {
            redirect('/pages/dashboard/get_emp_info', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['no_of_employees']    =   $this->employee_model->get_noof_employess();
            $data['no_of_employers']    =   $this->employee_model->get_noof_employers();

            $data['title']= '';
            $this->load->view('header/header_view',$data);
            $this->load->view("pages/index_view.php",$data);
            $this->load->view('footer/footer_view',$data);
        }
    }
}
```

route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index_controller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

i'll appreciate any type of help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are actually getting being reported as?

Comment: And your error is...

Comment: Can you edit your question with the error please. also are you getting the `echo "i am here"; die();` on your page?

Comment: Thank you for your response. i've solved that.

Comment: @HazratBilal, do you mean you already solved the error?

Comment: It would be nice to know what the actual error was and you could self answer it so that it is documented in case someone else comes with the same error.

Comment: Follow http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming